# Efficient way to find the token (word) index after a regular expression string search

Tags: python, regex, perl, string

I need to perform  a regular expression search for a string x in another string y, but I then need to know the token (word) index of the first character of the hit after tokenizing (splitting) string y using some other regular expression (e.g. white space). The first regular expression might find a substring, so I cannot guarantee that it will stop at the beginning of the token (word).

What would be the best algorithm to implement this. A simple approach would be the following:

1. Search for x in y using the first regular expression and get the character offset z
2. Split y into an array of elements using the second regular expression
3. Loop through the array of elements adding the length of each item to a variable LENGTH and adding 1 to a counter COUNTER
4. Stop the loop when LENGTH is greater or equal to z
5. The index of the token of the first character of the hit will be the value of COUNTER

(This assumes that the split function stores the splitting characters (e.g. white space) as array elements, which is very wasteful.

A concrete (simple) example: Suppose I want to know the token (word) index for the search "ade" in the string "The moon is made of cheese". The function should give me back the answer: 3 (for zero indexed arrays).

**==Edit==**
The algorithm also needs to work when the regex search crosses token boundaries. For example, it should again return the index "3" when searching for "de of ch" in "The moon is made of cheese".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your updates:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "The moon is made of cheese";
my $search = 'de of ch';
my $pos = index($string, $search);
if ($pos != -1) {
    my $substr = substr($string, 0, $pos);
    my @words = split /\s+/, $substr;
    print "found in word #", $#words, "\n";
} else {
    print "not found\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
found in word #3
```

Comment: Nice example, but this will only work if the regex search is within a token. I've edited the question to emphasize that it might not be.

Comment: Very nice! This is certainly *much* more efficient than the simple approach in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the first pattern in the string, then count the number of occurence of the second pattern string in the part of the string that is before the first pattern.

Here is a perl script doing the job:

```
    #!/bin/perl -w

    my $string = 'The moon is made of cheese';
    my $lookedfor = 'de of che';
    my $separator = q/\W+/;

    my $count = undef;
    if ($string =~ /(.*?)$lookedfor/) {
        # Keep the smallest (.*?) part of string before the match.
        my $firstpart = $1;

        $count = 0;
        # Count the number of separator 
        $count++ while $firstpart =~ m/$separator/g;
    }

    if (defined $count) {
        printf "index of '%s' in '%s' is %d\n", $lookedfor, $string, $count;
    } else {
        printf "No occurence of '%s' in '%s'\n", $lookedfor, $string;
    }
```

Comment: This certainly does the job and is much better than the simple method in the question. But, M42's approach is even more elegant. I'm going to mark his as the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm happy you liked my answer. M42' approach use 'index' which does not "perform a regular expression search for a string x" as required in the question. I agree that the split part is very efficient.

Comment: I agree that M42's approach used 'index' but it is trivial to change this to a regex expression and get the $pos value.